# Saxon / NodeJS : xslt3 command line says "Command line option -export requires a value"

Tags: command, xslt-3.0, saxon-js

I am trying to perform an XSLT transformation in NodeJS.
I found that Saxon looked like a good option (https://www.saxonica.com/download/javascript.xml), so I installed both saxon-js and xslt3 using npm.

Following the documentation here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/saxon-js (section Compiling a stylesheet), I cd to a folder containing my xsl file source.xsl and try to run the command :

`xslt3 -xsl:source.xsl -export:source.sef.json`

I get the error :
`Command line option -export requires a value`
which I don't understand.

If I try to run the complete command line like in the documentation

`xslt3 -xsl:source.xsl -export:source.sef.json -t -ns:##html5`

I get another error:
`The -ns: parameter requires one argument. + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterRequiresArgument`

I am quite lost here, any thought on what might be wrong ?

I tried to use blank spaces instead of colon in the command line, or changing the order of the paramters, but still get the same error.

Comment: Please try `xslt3 -xsl:source.xsl -export:source.sef.json -nogo` and report whether you still get the error. Also tell us exactly which version (e.g. the latest 2.5?) you use/installed. It also helps if you tell us which command line tool on which OS you use as the various command shells have different ways to interfere with command line options a tool might expose (like the `-ns:##html5`) and you need different type of escape characters or quotes to ensure the options is not misinterpreted and handled by the shell. If you are on Windows and the error comes from Powershell try cmd instead.

Comment: Hi; thanks for your reply. Adding -nogo gives the same error. npm list indicated versions 2.5.0 for xslt3 and saxon-js. I use VSCode to run the command line, on Windows. I tried xslt3 -xsl:source.xsl -export:source.sef.json with cmd , which gave me the same error. However I just tried xslt3 -xsl:source.xsl -export:source.sef.json -t -ns:##html in cmd and it seems to work ! So the problem might be the way VSCode handles characters/quotes...

Comment: I still think the error "CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterRequiresArgument" smells like Powershell being involved and complaining; I have had my own problems of using `xslt3` with Powershell: https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/5/topics/8802. I don't know what CSCode uses as the command shell. Good to hear that you finally found some working example with `xslt3 -xsl:source.xsl -export:source.sef.json -t -ns:##html` in the `cmd` shell, makes me wonder why `xslt3 -xsl:source.xsl -export:source.sef.json` doesn't work in `cmd`.

Comment: When I try `xslt3` with only `-xsl` and `-export` I tend to get an error like "Transformation failure: Error XTDE0044 No source input supplied for apply-templates invocation", that's why for pure compilation to SEF I think you mostly need the `-nogo`. But perhaps your XSLT starts with an initial template.

Comment: As you're using VSCode, have you tried DeltaXML's XSLT/Extension for VSCode?
This invokes SaxonJS as a process using VS Code tasks. Unfortunately, it doesn't yet support the `-ns` flag. I'll add that in the next update. Here are the docs anyway: https://deltaxml.github.io/vscode-xslt-xpath/run-xslt.html

Comment: I've just updated VS Code (1.5.8) to support an `unprefixedElementNames` property in tasks.json. This is probably a problem with missing quotes as VS code invokes SaxonJS in a process (that doesn't need quotes) with the following command with no problem. `npx xslt3 -xsl:test-xsl/src/new.xsl -s:/Documents/test-xsl/src/new.xsl -ns:##html5 -export:new.sef.json -o:/Users/philipfearon/Documents/any.xml -nogo `

Comment: I don't have VSCode installed but I suspect that's the essence of your problem; perhaps it's treating ":" as a special character in some way. Try putting the parameters in quotes. Or, as you say, use the normal command line interpreter rather than VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is caused by the VSCode command line requiring the colon character (":") to be escaped in some way.